# How do you display user name on Facebook tab without forcing user to allow

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-iframe, facebook-fbml

How do you display the user name / visitor name on a Facebook tab (Facebook app created in an Iframe) without requiring the user to accept additional permissions.

I have tried to use PHP and other examples that I have seen, however they all seem to be out of date or I am missing some type of code to implement.
This should not be in FBML as it will be depreciated very soon on Facebook.

Does anybody have an entire code example (since I must be missing something) of what it would take to implement how they have done it here: https://www.facebook.com/Greenwords - Notice that it does not require the user to click on anything in order to display the name.
Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used to be able to do this using facebooks FBML syntax.  However, as you have stated, these methods are old/depricated.
Taken from the [facebook FBML documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/) :

> We are deprecating FBML. On Jan 1, 2012: FBML will no longer be supported on Platform. June 1, 2012: FBML apps will no longer work. All FBML endpoints are removed. If you are building a new application on Facebook.com, please implement your application using HTML, JavaScript and CSS. You can use our JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins to embedded many of the same social features available in FBML.

So.. to answer your question - you'll have to build your own application and request basic information about the user.  Using old and deprecated methods are **not** a good idea.  Facebook has publicly stated that they will no longer support it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I really do not want to use FBML  as it will no longer be supported in a few months. However I will for the moment if there is no other way.
I am aware that I do have to request basic information.  The problem is that any and all methods that I have attempted have not worked without requiring additional permissions to be accepted by the user.  As per the example, it can be done.  I just have no idea how to accomplish this.   I am looking for the code that would accomplish this as well as the pre-requisite code proceeding it.    Thanks.

Comment: Try looking at this feature of the facebook JS SDK...
[FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I do not see the resolution there.

Answer (score 0):

I basically used to take a live stream or comments box and iframe that showing the users name or photo, then position it where I wanted.

Comment: Very interesting approach. Because it must be presented as text in the middle of a background image, I am not sure that I can use this.  I appreciate the suggestion though.   It is amazing how difficult this is for such a simplistic goal.